# How to delete a sequence of characters from an SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server

I have an SQL view of 1000 records, and in each record i have the string "EXO" in ST_DES(as shown in the picture in the second table cell)  in the middle or in the last of the string of the record, 
Is there any solution to delete any STRING 'EXO' from all the records by SQL request?

[image: View content]

Answer (score 4):

Why yes there is! and its quite simple!

```
 UPDATE VR_ART 
 SET ST_DES = REPLACE(ST_DES, 'EXO', '')
 WHERE CHARINDEX('EXO', ST_DES,1)>0
```

Replace literally does what it says. Its a nifty function youll end up using a lot i assume.

Comment: Worth nothing that I used a where clause checking for the existence of the string first - would hate to tie up the whole table and only a handful of records get updated.

Comment: Greate thanx a lot

Comment: @Soulef if it fixes your issue - hook a brother up with a answer mark and an  upvote <3